# Express JS - Load data from a REST call and set to an Application variable when the Application starts up

Tags: node.js, express

I have a middleware that load some JSON data from a REST API.

loadDataStartup.js

```
'use strict';

const db_contants = require('./db_contants');

async function loadData () {
    console.log("*** loadData() called");
    var equipmentCategoryArr = await db_contants.getEquipmentCategory();
    return equipmentCategoryArr;
}

module.exports = {loadData};
```

In my app.js, I need to set the data to an Application-level variable by app.set such that it can be later used by other Routers.

app.js

```
const { loadData } = require('./db/loadDataStartup');
var app = express();
app.set('dataOnStartup', async loadData());
```

When I ran `npm start`, it threw the following error:

```
app.set('dataOnStartup', async loadData());
                         ^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I am with node.js version 8.11.3.

Comment: You don't use the async keyword when calling, and you don't need to call it. `app.set('…', loadData)`

Comment: Thanks! I made the change but when I called `app.get('dataOnStartup')` it actually printed out the function `loadData()` itself rather than the array object result from the REST call I wanted.

Comment: The problem is that `loadData` so you can exactly do `app.set('…', loadData())` or else you get a promise. You could do `app.set('...', await loadData())` to await promise completion but that'd still have to be in an async function itself.

Comment: I tried to change to `app.set('dataOnStartup', await loadData());` as you pointed out but ended up with the same error `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` on `await` this time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't do `async callAsyncFn()`, but `await callAsyncFn()`. So `async loadData()` is a syntax error. What you probably wanted to do was `await loadData()`. But you also can't do this in the entry-level app file, because this statement is not in an `async` function (you can only `await` inside `async` functions).

The workaround would be using an `async` IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression), like this:

```
const { loadData } = require("./db/loadDataStartup");
var app = express();

(async function() {
    app.set("dataOnStartup", await loadData());
    // The rest of your app startup logic
})();
```